# Dividing columns in to ranges in R

Tags: r

I would like to know how divide columns in to ranges. Sample data is as follows.

```
Name    V1.1    V1.2    V2.1    V2.2    V3.1    V3.2
AAA    Skill1   Level3  skill2 Level1   Skill3 Level2
BBB    Skill1   Level4  Skill2 Level2   Skill3 Level1
```

Expected output is

```
Name  Level1 Level2  Level3  Level4
AAA   Skill2 Skill3  Skill1   NA
BBB   Skill3 Skill2  NA       Skill1
```

Could write the code till the Input only.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't this be a part of your other question?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `melt/dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df1), measure= list(seq(2, ncol(df1), by =2), 
    seq(3, ncol(df1), by=2))), Name~value2, value.var='value1')
#     Name Level1 Level2 Level3 Level4
#1:  AAA skill2 Skill3 Skill1     NA
#2:  BBB Skill3 Skill2     NA Skill1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("AAA", "BBB"),
 V1.1 = c("Skill1", "Skill1"
), V1.2 = c("Level3", "Level4"), V2.1 = c("skill2", "Skill2"), 
V2.2 = c("Level1", "Level2"), V3.1 = c("Skill3", "Skill3"
), V3.2 = c("Level2", "Level1")), .Names = c("Name", "V1.1", 
"V1.2", "V2.1", "V2.2", "V3.1", "V3.2"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: I am able to the count of skills under level. I would like to see the names of the skill

Comment: @Ram Isn't this the same as your expected output?

Comment: Expected output is to see the names of the skills under level ranges. From your code I am able to see the count of skills under each level

Comment: @Ram Sorry, I don't understand.  I get the same output as your expected.

Comment: @Ram I tried to convert it to `factor` and then used the code and got the same result.

Comment: Thats not a factor class. All I need trying to see is the skillnames as skill1 ,skill2  rather than seeing 1,2,3 under levels

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105995/discussion-between-ram-and-akrun).